# Php artisan queue:work doesn't work with supervisor

Tags: laravel, supervisord

I have installed & configured supervisor.

`ps -ax` shows 10 processes such as:
`php /home/vagrant/Sites/mysite/artisan queue:work --tries=1`

However when I put something in queue it stays there and nothing happens. But if I run this command manually (even under vagrant user, exactly how it does supervisor) everything works.

I use Redis for keeping queues.

What can be the reason?

**update**

So, here is some additional info, since I really couldn't figure it out.

Laravel 5.5 version

Actually I have **two** supervisor configs for 2 projects. First one seemed to be working. Second doesn't. I mean, I can see the processes by `ps -ax`, but nothing happens. Both configs are identical:

`[program:mysite-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/vagrant/Sites/mysite/artisan queue:work --tries=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=vagrant
numprocs=10
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/vagrant/Sites/mysite/worker.log`

Also I couldn't figure out how can I enable and disabled some configs (like `en2site` for supervisord :) )

So, when I put something in the queue I can see it in redis. Then I manually run `php /home/vagrant/Sites/mysite/artisan queue:work --tries=1` under vagrant user and queue jobs are dispatched and run. But only if I run the command manually =\

Comment: Please share your `*.conf` file

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Matz I updated my post :)

Comment: try `sudo supervisorctl reread`.. then..`sudo supervisorctl update`.. finally.. `sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*`

Comment: No idea why, but it started working. Forgot as a nightmare..

Answer (score 1):

I was about the same problem.

The issue is apears becouse supervisor when call
php /home/vagrant/Sites/mysite/artisan queue:work --tries=1

actualy not in project working directory, and artisan cant find .env file.

so you have some option to handle this:

1. set your enviroment variables from .env file
   or
2. add directory parametr to your supervisor config
   directory="path/to/your/project"
   or
3. set set_include_path in php.ini to your project folder